# HTML form submit sends no data

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="login_form">
  <input type="text" name="log_login_form"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="password" name="log_password_form"/>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" value="Login" id="log_submit" disabled="disabled" name="action" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">Login</button>
</form>
```

After a submit the page refreshes, but with php server not getting any data. `var_dump($_POST);` returns `array(0) {}`.

In the form `action=""` refers to `index.php` that handles form submits.
(Changing to `action="index.php"` didn't help)

The button has some extra attributes for a script disabling it until all inputs are filled:

```
login_form.find('input').on('keyup blur', function () {
  if (login_form.valid()) {
    $('#log_submit').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#log_submit').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Removing the script and changing the button to a regular one didn't help either so I guess the problem doesn't lie there.

I've also tried submitting from external button using javascript:
`<button onclick="document.getElementById('login_form').submit();"></button>` (Ended up with the same behaviour.)

And a throwaway try (that I've read, might work) was adding/ removing the `/` slashes before closing tags.

Could it be a problem with my php configuration?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you have to remove `disabled="disabled"` from button

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem: http://i.imgur.com/kIUx1fD.png

Comment: @SuperUser — From the question: "The button has some extra attributes for a script disabling it until all inputs are filled. (Removing the script and changing the button to a regular one didn't help either.)"

Comment: @Quentin but when submit button is disable, how op can submit the form, or he has to share the full code

Comment: This is for chrome, but other browsers have such tools.
Open inspector and select the network tab, tick "Preserve log", then fill in the form and submit. Select the request from the list and at the bottom of the "Headers" tab should be the post data. This should also show any redirects that may be happening which could be causing the post data to go missing.


Ninja-edit: I should have mentioned, this is just to diagnose if the issue is with the sending of the form or receiving it.

Comment: @SuperUser look at the JS code in the latest edit. Once the user has filled in the appropriate fields the button will be enabled. This is a non-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690488/craig)'s answer I was able to track down the issue. As the form data was there and GET method was working as intended.

Turns out it's caused by a bug in an IDE I was using. This bit of code fixed the problem:

```
$_POST = array(); //workaround for broken PHPstorm
parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_POST);
```

(credit: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999125/comments/203891884)